# Crasheo de app cuando oprimo recyclerwiew

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, recyclerview

Estoy haciendo un sistema de logueo que mande  a diferentes clases, funciona pero cuando mando a una clase que tiene menu desplegable usada con fragments y doy a una fragment que me debería dejar ver los usuarios se cierra la app
En el logcat aparece lo siguiente:

```
2020-06-28 14:52:56.483 26337-26337/com.example.tallerof E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tallerof, PID: 26337
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.tallerof.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment.onCreateView(GalleryFragment.java:31)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Fragment donde tengo puesto todo el codigo:

```
  package com.example.tallerof.ui.gallery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.tallerof.R;
import com.example.tallerof.adapters.UsuariosAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

    ArrayList<String> ListadeDatos;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;



    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Recycler1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    ListadeDatos=new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i<=50; i++){
        ListadeDatos.add("Dato # "+i+"");

    }

        UsuariosAdapter adapter= new UsuariosAdapter(ListadeDatos);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return null;
    }


}
```

Adaptador:

```
   package com.example.tallerof.adapters;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder;

import com.example.tallerof.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UsuariosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsuariosAdapter.UsuariosHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> ListadeDatos;

    public UsuariosAdapter(ArrayList<String> listadeDatos) {
        ListadeDatos = listadeDatos;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UsuariosHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_regis,null,false);
        return new UsuariosHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsuariosHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.AsignarDatos(ListadeDatos.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ListadeDatos.size();
    }

    public class UsuariosHolder extends ViewHolder {
        TextView dato;



        public UsuariosHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            dato=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Recycler1);
        }

        public void AsignarDatos(String s) {
            dato.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Y finalmente layouts:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Img_Regis"
                android:layout_width="142dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/descarga" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="244dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/NumR"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textSize="27dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/NombreR"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/MatriT"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/SemestreR"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/FacR"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/IdR_R"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/AceptadoR"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/Recycler1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Puede que la solución sea más clara que el agua, pero la verdad es que le he estado dando vueltas por horas para evitar preguntar pero finalmente me dí por vencido, si ustedes pueden verlo sería muy grata su ayuda

---

Hola, lo cambie como lo puso y ya no sale error allí, pero ahora sale este error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a
> null object reference at
> com.example.tallerof.adapters.UsuariosAdapter$UsuariosHolder.AsignarDatos(UsuariosAdapter.java:53)

En el adaptador, podrías ayudarme a saber por que salió?

Comment: Recuerda que si alguna respuesta ayudo a solucionar el problema debes marcarla como soluciòn para que ayude a otros miembros de la comunidad, revisa [tour] , saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El LogCat especifica un error:

> Process: com.example.tallerof, PID: 26337
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)'
> on a null object reference

Esto se debe a que dentro del mètodo `onCreateView()` no estas inflando la vista en donde se encuentra el `RecyclerView` con id `Recycler1`, de hecho lo estas buscando en la Activity ( `getActivity()` ) donde seguramente no se encuentra.

```
 recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Recycler1);
```

Lo que debes realizar es inflar el layout del Fragment que contenga el RecyclerView y ademas debes retornar una vista y no un valor null, por ejemplo, suponiendo que el layout de tu Fragment que contiene el RecyclerView es `my_fragment.xml` :

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

        //recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Recycler1);
        recyclerView = myView.findViewById(R.id.Recycler1);
        ...
        ...
        return myView;
    }
```

Revisa este [ejemplo de un Fragment cargando un RecyclerView](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-RecyclerView-and-Fragment/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jorgesys/recyclerviewinfragment/ListFragment.java).

---

Con respecto a este error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
> object reference at
> com.example.tallerof.adapters.UsuariosAdapter$UsuariosHolder.AsignarDatos(UsuariosAdapter.java:53)

Se debe a que el TextView no existe dentro de `item_regis.xml` de hecho me parece que no deberìa ser `R.id.Recycler1`, seguramente este no es un TextView, revisa cual es el id correcto del Id y corrigelo.

```
public UsuariosHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

       // dato=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Recycler1);
          dato=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.?????);

    }
```

Comment: El TextView que tratas de obtener no existe en el layout, agregue esa informaciòn en mi respuesta.

Comment: Sí, cuando vi el codigo me di cuenta de ello, gracias realmente, me has salvado de una buena